# CiviDiscount - applying sales tax on discounted price rather than original price

Tags: civicontribute, cividiscount, taxes

I found this in the CiviCRM issue tracker - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16861

This is a pretty major bug for us - Has anyone resolved this issue on their own?

Essentially, when a discount code is applied, tax is applied to the original amount rather than the discounted amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've patched Cividiscount extension which now ensures that the discount also gets applied to VAT/Sales Tax when it's applied to price options.
Here is the PR link: https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/131

Have also updated the ticket: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16861

Thanks

Comment: Just an update on this! I did another PR for the same which also considers "Fixed Amount" as well as "Percent" based discounts. Here is the link: https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/133 The PR has now been merged.

Answer (score 1):

we're about to release a patch for this which will fix the discount. I'll push back to this thread once released, hopefully within the next couple of working days.

Comment: Hi. I am on the latest 3.3. version and this is still not working. Our membership is $220 + 10% tax but when we add a 50% tax it makes the amount $99 + $ 22 tax. So it seems like it also miscalculates the base amount.